# terminate onBackPressed() while Interstitial onAdOpend()

Tags: android, admob, terminate, interstitial, onbackpressed

I want to terminate the **back press button** while the **interstitial ads are displayed** onAdOpened. But I couldn't do this, Could you help me, please?

```
public void terminateBackPressForAds(){
            interstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener(){
                @Override
                public void onAdOpened() {
                   moveTaskToBack(false);
                   super.onAdOpened();
               }
           });
       }
```

Comment: I think it's against [AdMob policy](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6128543) unless it's a "Rewarded Ad".

Comment: @Rajarshi is correct it's against AdMob policy in some way. I suggest you use `Rewarded Video`.

Comment: @NithisKumar, Hello could you give me a rewarded video tutorial link, or How to use and when use rewarded ads.